# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php, laravel, migration, composer-php, migrate

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wTgu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your migration scripts. One of your migration script has an invalid syntax in it.